Nonabelian groups where every element has small order
Let $G$ be a finite nonabelian group with the property that if $g \in G$, then
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord} \ord(g) \leqslant 10 \log_2 |G|, $$
where $\ord(g)$ is the order of the element $g$, the logarithm is binary, and $|G|$ is the cardinality of $G$. The number $10$ here is not important, one could replace it by any constant larger than $1.5$, say.
Is there a characterization of such groups $G$? If not, I would also be interested in hearing about any infinite family of nonabelian groups which has this property -- unfortunately, my knowledge of nonabelian groups is sparse enough that I don't know any examples of groups with this property.

This question is related to my earlier question on approximate tilings. If $G$ has an element $t$ with $\ord(t) > 10\log_2|G|$, then one can use it to construct a $0.9$-approximate tiling of $G$ of the right size by taking $A = \{1, t, t^2, \cdots, t^{k-1}\}$ where $k = \log_2 |G| - 100 \log_2\log_2|G|$ and $B = B_1B_2$ where $B_1$ is a complete set of coset representatives of the subgroup $\langle t \rangle$ generated by $t$ and $B_2 = \{ t^k, t^{2k}, t^{3k}, \cdots, t^{rk}\}$ where $r$ is the largest integer so that $rk < \ord(t)$.

I should warn you that for the monster, the largest order of an element is 119, whereas $\log_2|G|$ is about 179.

"Nonabelian" may not be the limitation you want. D_4 x (Z/2)^n is, for every n, a nonabelian group of exponent 4 and order 2^(n+3). Presumably this is "cheating" for your intended purpose but I don't know what additional conditions you would want (besides non-abelian) to exclude it.

You should put a restriction on the rank, as shown by the example of Dave Rusin. Even with that, I don’t believe there is a classification, the size of the largest finite $2$-generated group of exponent $n$ probably grows much faster than exponential in $n$ (see « restricted Burnside problem »).

See https://doi.org/10.1017/S144678870000121X, in particular in the second section for an infinite family.

...In any case, this question subsumes full description of finite Burnside groups, and progress in this direction is pretty much absent since Zelmanov settled restricted Burnside conjecture.

One notable family of examples is $G = A_n^m$, where $m$ is chosen as large as possible subject to $G$ being $2$-generated. It is well-known that $m \sim n! / 4$, so the order of $G$ is more than exponential in $n!$ but its exponent is roughly $\exp(\sqrt{n \log n})$. Similar analysis applies to direct powers of any simple group.

Thanks to everyone for the comments! Let me first address the comments of the Daves. I am primarily interested in groups in the asymptotic limit $|G| \to \infty$, so an individual group like the monster is not too concerning unless one can leverage that to create an infinite family of groups. (Though it is good to know that the monster has the property I ask.) As Dave Rusin mentions, $D_4 \times (\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$ is indeed cheating for me, since then I can tile it by using a tiling for $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$. I'll amend the question after thinking a bit more about what criterion I want exactly.

If you do not bound the number of generators, then you can fix a prime $p$ and consider all the $d$-generated finite Burnside groups. If you do bound the number of generators, then the maximal order of an element has to go to infinity by the Restricted Burnside Problem. However, I am not sure how fast.
